# Python : List elements are connected, how to separate

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def list():
    mylist = [[0,0,0,0]]*3
    mylist[1][2] = 8013
    print(mylist)
```

Output:

```
[[0,0,8013,0],[0,0,8013,0],[0,0,8013,0]]
```

Wanted output:

```
[[0,0,0,0],[0,0,8013,0],[0,0,0,0]]
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Could you please link to the duplicate thread? I tried searching, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Refresh the page. You should see the duplicate linked in an edit to your post

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Ah thanks! Even that one is marked as possible duplicate... Should I just delete this, or let it stay so others have a better chance of searching and finding the problem?

Comment: Leave it up - for exactly that reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `eval` on `repr`.

```
mylist = eval(repr([[0,0,0,0]]*3))
```

or use list comp to produce the list

```
mylist = [[0,0,0,0] for _ in range(3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `mylist = [[0 for _ in xrange(4)] for _ in xrange(3)]`

Using `*` will cause Python to use the same object for the whole list, and that's why when you change any one of the element in the list, you are changing the rest of them.